# IOError: [Errno 2] after moving files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am hoping to achieve the following ops using the function below:

1. Loop through and read all .xlsx files from a directory
2. Convert each file to a .csv and write it to a sub_directory
3. Move the (already read) .xlsx file to a junk directory

```
def lookup_convert():

    source_dir = os.path.join("/Users/jaypuzhakkara/Downloads/","path_new")
    push_dir = os.path.join(source_dir,'pushed_files')
    oldfiles = os.path.join(source_dir,'old_files')
    if not os.path.exists(push_dir):
        os.makedirs(push_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(oldfiles):
        os.makedirs(oldfiles)
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
           if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
               head, tail = os.path.split(file)
               filename = os.path.splitext(tail)[0]
               read_file = pd.read_excel(source_dir + '/' + file)
               read_file.to_csv (push_dir + '/' + filename + '.csv',  
                  index = None, 
                  header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig') 
               shutil.move(source_dir + '/' + file, oldfiles)
```

When I run this, the .xlsx file gets read, exported as a CSV into a subdirectory, and then moved to a junk directory, however, I am getting this error at the end.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BOS_csv_push.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "BOS_csv_push.py", line 26, in main
    lookup_convert()
  File "BOS_csv_push.py", line 19, in lookup_convert
    read_file = pd.read_excel(source_dir + '/' + file)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jaypuzhakkara/Downloads/path_new/report.xlsx'
```

Is it because it's trying to reopen the same file after it has been moved? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: That seems to make sense to me.  what does `os.path.isfile('/Users/jaypuzhakkara/Downloads/old_files/report.xlsx')` return?

Comment: You could also simplify the script is you use `glob.glob`.  You could lose the `os.walk` for loop and change the `for file in files` loop to `for file in glob(f'{source_dir}/*.xlsx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a `break` statement on the inner for loop and that seemed to have fixed the issue.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
           head, tail = os.path.split(file)
           filename = os.path.splitext(tail)[0]
           read_file = pd.read_excel(source_dir + '/' + file)
           read_file.to_csv (push_dir + '/' + filename + '.csv',  
              index = None, 
              header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig') 
           shutil.move(source_dir + '/' + file, oldfiles)
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were running into issues with:

```
read_file = pd.read_excel(source_dir + '/' + file)
read_file.to_csv (push_dir + '/' + filename + '.csv', index = None, 
                  header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

That is making a file is a .`xlsx.csv` extension.  A better approach would be to remove the `.xlsx` exension with `push_dir + '/' + filename[:-3] + '.csv'`

If you wanted to simplify your function, you could use `glob.glob` to find excel files directly.  Something like:

```
import glob
def lookup_convert():
    for file in glob(f'{source_dir}/*.xlsx'):
        head, tail = os.path.split(file)
        filename = os.path.splitext(tail)[0]
        pd.read_excel(file).to_csv (f'{push_dir}/{os.path.basename(file)[:-3]}xlsx',  
                                                       index = None, 
                                                       header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig') 
        shutil.move(source_dir + '/' + file, oldfiles)

        if not os.path.isfile(file) and os.path.isfile(f'{push_dir}/{file}.xlsx')
            print(f'Moved File {file} to f'{push_dir}/{file[:-3]}xlsx')
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after making the changes: ```push_dir + '/' + filename[:-3] + '.csv'```